# A variable in nginx.conf that changes when NGINX server is restarted

Tags: nginx

In the nginx.conf file, is there a variable that changes only when NGINX server is restarted?
Or how to implement a customized variable that changes only when NGINX server is restarted?

I have tried to use **set directive** and **geo directive** as follow:

```
set $timeStamp '$time_iso8601';
```

it will change with http request.

Could anyone help for this? Thanks!

Comment: What's your goal, to get nginx uptime?

Comment: Actually I want to monitor every restart of NGINX server and generate a time stamp for it. This is for code version control.  So do you know how to monitor restart of NGINX server, or is there a variable which could be used as a flag in nignx.conf? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is not actually a variable containing this built into nginx.

I'm assuming that there is some outside system actually handling the restarts (or reloads, which is more common) themselves, something like `systemd`, `supervisord`, etc.

In that case, you can have a script that generates a file that sets the variable, which will be loaded when `nginx` reads the configuration.

For example, `/usr/local/nginx/conf/restart_var.conf' might contain:

```
set $custom_nginx_restart "2017-07-01 3:15:00Z";
```

You would include this in your `server` block.

The would just be generated by a script like:

```
echo "set \$custom_nginx_restart `date`;" > /usr/local/nginx/conf/restart_var.conf
```

Alternatively, you can generate something like:

```
map $http_host $custom_nginx_restart {
    default "2017-07-03 3:15:00Z";
}
```

This can then be included in your `http` block.

Note that this would apply both on reloads and restart.